# Code-formatted links aren't highlighted blue

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design

Links wrapped around `` `code` `` snippets aren't highlighted as links, so they're hard to notice. This should probably behave more like SU and SO, where they're still highlighted blue even though they're code-formatted.